# C++17 what is the fastest way to convert list ( or other container ) to string cross platform

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring, stdlist

i have list of strings

```
std::list<std::string> list = { "--version", "--setcolor", "--setint" };
list.push_back("--command1");
list.push_back("--command2");
list.push_back("--command3");
```

basically list of commands which in the end like to convert them to string
the list, in the end, can contain up to 100 commands.
what is the fastest way to do it in c++17?

**UPDATE**
It can be also array or other container
the end result should be like this :

std::string s = "--version --setcolor --setint --command1 --command2 --command3";

Thanks

Comment: are you speaking strictly of concatenating all the strings in the list? (please provide, for the sample code given, the desired string output)

Comment: `for (const auto& l : list) some_string += s;` ? Is this too slow?

Comment: why are you looking for "fastest" when the list has only up to 100 entries? Is it really "fastest" what you need, or maybe just something that works?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 - yes - if you fail to use `string::reserve` to make sure in advance that the string has the capacity to hold the entire desired output - but this is stuff that is not new to C++17 - this efficient use of string (reserve first, then concatenate) is known from the beginning.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to verify that building your string is actually too slow?

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: It's two lines of code (at most) to do it "fast" - sum the sizes of the substrings, then reserve space - and it's a standard idiom - contrary to popular belief not _all_ "micro optimizations" need be profiled to ensure that they're needed and that they don't add "needless" complexity. Sometimes, e.g., this case, it is faster/easier/correct to just "optimize' it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `std::string` as an accumulator (e.g., "string buffer", as seen in Java or C#) is standard practice in C++ and there's nothing C++11/14/17/20 adds to make it "faster".

Simply add up the length of the substrings - and the delimiters between them - `string::reserve` enough capacity in your target string, then `string::append` away ...

[@Justin answered in a comment, but putting it here as well because comments are ephemeral]

In C++ strings are modifiable (unlike other languages like Java and C# where they're immutable).  So you can change them, including adding characters to them (e.g., via `string::append`).

There are two relevant concepts: the string's *size* - which is how many characters it has right now, and the string's *capacity* - which is how much it could hold given the storage already allocated to it.  If the capacity is the same as the size then adding anything to the string will require a new allocation of storage from the heap, and a copy of the current contents of the string into it (and a deallocation of the old storage back to the heap.)  (*)  If the capacity is *larger* than the size then appending new characters will not require that allocation/copy/deallocation if the new characters will fit in the capacity available.

If you're doing multiple appends to a string this might mean multiple alloc/copy/dealloc cycles. Which is expensive.

So instead you *reserve* additional capacity up front:  By calling `string::reserve` the capacity is increased to the amount specified in one shot.  Then you append all your stuff bit by bit (byte by byte ..., substring by substring) and it'll all fit (if you calculated the necessary capacity correctly) without any additional alloc/copy/dealloc.

`string::reserve` is discussed [here at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve).  While you're there check out `string::capacity` - to find the current capacity of the string, and why not also look at `string::resize` - used to shrink the capacity until it is just as large as needed for the current contents of the string.

(*) Yes I'm leaving out the small string optimization ...

Comment: loop the list and append ? why i need the string::reserve?

Comment: @user63898 [`std::string::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) "Informs a `std::basic_string` object of a planned change in size, so that it can manage the storage allocation appropriately. ... new storage is allocated, and `capacity()` is made equal or greater than `new_cap`. " If you `reserve` upfront, there's only one allocation: the initial call to `reserve()`. If you remove the `reserve()`, the string will allocate every time its size exceeds twice\* the previous allocation (not necessarily 2x, but that's common), leaving the final allocation too large.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer @davidbak and  Justin , but how can i know the capacity of the strings inside the list ? do i need to save it each time i pushback string into the list or there any other way ?

Comment: @user63898 - you loop over the list and add the sizes up, of course!  do it just before you reserve the space ...